# change border color without changing border width

Tags: html, css, colors, border

When I change color of input text border, the border width seems to change to.
How can I avoid this?

```
border-color: orange;
```

[image: input border color]

I also tried

```
border: 1px solid orange
```

and the width is no like original input and the height is modified...

[image: border color]

I want exactly the same as original but with an another color

Comment: Could you please post any other CSS code affecting both the grey and orange borders?  That orange border looks larger than 1px.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue - https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/brbPWB - notice that changing the border color doesn't change border thickness

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/u1bub4cm/
I'm working with chrome

Comment: @Firemen26 that is correct!, [@]Danield for see the bug: zoom MAXIMUM and compare both borders. (me too have the same problem)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

border: 1px solid orange;

It seems there is another style like outline for input. Set outline:0;

Comment: please see edit

Comment: the answer from @Mohsen Govahi not resolve problem: "change color without change width border" (see pictures of [@]Firemen26). –

Answer (score -1):

You have to use this css style:

```
border: npx solid orange
```

`n` is the size of border (e.g. border: 5px solid orange)