# css change ONLY background, not border

Tags: css

please look this code:

```
<input type="text" /> (I need this with background color)

<input type="text" style="background:gold;" />

<input type="text" style="background:gold;outline:0;" />

<input type="text" style="background:gold;-webkit-appearance:none;" />
```

how I can have background = `gold` without change border ?

if you do ZOOM then you see `border-width` change

PD:
this Q is about background, not borders
([change border color without changing border width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263928/change-border-color-without-changing-border-width))

Answer (score 0):

Yes , i have looked your issue, please use the following code lines

input{

```
background: gold;
border: 1px solid grey;
border-radius: 2px;
```

}

input:focus, input:focus-visible,  input:hover{

```
 outline: 0;
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Narendra you can see your code `CHANGE border-width value`.

Answer (score -1):

This is as close as it gets
check this post:
[changing backgroundColor changes border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781693/changing-backgroundcolor-changes-border)

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" style="background-color:gold;border:thin solid grey;border-radius: 2px;" />
```

Comment: thanks @Dibash Sapkota you can see the result is the same: `border box is changed`

Comment: You can change border color and also make border none

Comment: master @Dibash Sapkot can you see the difference into FIRST BOX and the others? Please do ZOOM, then you see: `the border ORIGINAL is losed`

Comment: Many thanks by your help master @Dibash Sapkota even when you use `style="background-color:gold;border:thin solid grey` the `border-width` change (please do ZOOM)

Comment: yes while changing input background default border properties are changed ,I tried to revert by JavaScript  but it didn't happen

Comment: master @Dibash Sapkota that is a "BUG" from BROWSERS / CSS ?

Comment: It seems so,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781693/changing-backgroundcolor-changes-border       other peoples also have same problem 10 years ago

Comment: oh my god!!, 10 years and yet not exist a slution? Really is very confuse then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233097/discussion-between-dibash-sapkota-and-stackoverflow).